# Windows 10: How do I stop windows from displaying the sticky notes app as a window?

Tags: windows, windows-10, sticky-notes

I don't want my sticky notes to come up as a window while I'm switching between applications. I don't want them to come up in the application switcher or appear in the taskbar as an active window:

[image]

I just want them to be there when I go to my desktop. How do I do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want them to come up in the application switcher or appear in the taskbar as an active window.  I just want them to be there when I go to my desktop. How do I do something like that?

*You cannot*.

Sticky Notes is a UWP application . There isn’t a way to hide it, unless, you close the application.